# What is the topology on the free group with $n$ generators?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently reading *Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory, and Applications* by Einsiedler and Ward and came upon this: Exercise 9.24. Show that if $G$ is a topological group with property (T), and 
is a continuous homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$ with dense image, then $G'$ also has
property (T). Conclude that the free group $F$ (with at least one generator) does not
have property (T).

I think I'm meant to construct a continuous homomorphism from the free group $F$ generated by $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ with dense image, since those two are known to not have property (T).

Before doing so, I need to know what the topology on the free group is. Would this topology make $F$ the universal topological group such that for any topological group $G$ and any map $f: \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow G$, there is a continuous homomorphism $\phi: F \rightarrow G$ such that $\phi \circ i = f$ ($i$ being the embedding)? If this is the case, how can I construct this topology explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the discrete topology on the free group with $n$-generators $F(x_1,...,x_n)$ (every subset is open and closed) and define $f:F(x_1,...,x_n)\rightarrow Z$ by $f(x_i)=1$.

Comment: I agree that that would technically solve the problem, but I want to use the topology on F which gives a universal property, or which is in standard use in math.

Comment: That is the discrete topology. @user25959